# Symfony2, Blank page every time on first attempt website, after reload/refresh its working

Tags: symfony, nginx, centos, symfony-2.8, php-5.5

I'm getting blank on first time when i open my website and after if i refresh that page again then it loads perfectly, I'm using web server with following my website configuration:

```
PHP 5.5.38
NGINX with PHP-FPM
Centos7
Symfony 2.8.4-DEV
```

I have changed owner and group in [www.conf]

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
```

However I have enabled all errors every where in php, nginx, php-fpm but unluckily i didn't get any error anywhere in my server. Always when i first time load my website showing blank page in production (`app.php`) and its working fine in Development (`app_dev.php`) even in first load.
I have applied all rules, permissions but no any luck, `full access 777 rights to app/cache/* & app/logs/*` . Page is blank & there is nothing also in view soures its all blank with no any error.

**NGINX.CONFIG file**

**[image: NGINX]**

Here is my developer console with blank page

[image]

Thanks in advance for any kind of help....

Comment: Have a look into the browsers developer console. Does your document return with 200 OK status? Does your document have a size? Any client-related loading errors?

Comment: @MichelFeldheim no there is no any error in developer console

Comment: Do you get a 0-Byte document with 200 OK HTTP status?

Comment: @MichelFeldheim i have added developer console screen shot in question desc: its 200 OK response

Comment: Have you tried ```php app/console cache:clear --env=prod```?